# Error: Cannot find module 'commander' whentrying to start the app

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, hosting

```
App 124691 output: Error: Cannot find module 'commander'
App 124691 output: Require stack:
App 124691 output: - /home/stuff/test/index.js
App 124691 output: - /opt/passenger-5.3.7-9.el7.cloudlinux/src/helper-scripts/node-loader.js
App 124691 output:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
App 124691 output:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
App 124691 output:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
App 124691 output:     at Module.require (/opt/passenger-5.3.7-9.el7.cloudlinux/src/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
App 124691 output:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
App 124691 output:     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/crypbotc/repositories/crypto-trading-bot/index.js:1:17)
App 124691 output:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
App 124691 output:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
App 124691 output:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
App 124691 output:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14) {
App 124691 output:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
```

It is running on shared hosting and i dont have "SUDO" or root access to it.
I have tired to install and rebuild and whatever else google has shown me but with no luck sofar.